# Creating patterns with multidimensional arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i have a dilemma. My code is supposed to output a diagonal pattern of numbers using for loops and a 5 by 5 two-dimensional array. I am to fill the array up with zeros and have the for loop fill it in with the numbers I want. So far i have done this successfully. However, they are in the wrong order. I want the 80 to be at the top right and the 5 to be at the bottom left.

The output should be like this:

```
0  0  0  0  80
0  0  0  40 0
0  0  20 0  0
0  10 0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0
```

Current source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int the_array[5][5] =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };

    int dia = 5;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (x = 4; x >= 0; --x)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
        {
            if (x == y)
            {
                the_array[x][y] = dia;
                dia *= 2;
            }

            printf(" %d ", the_array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Split the loops up into two passes.  Set the array in the first pass, then print it in the second.  That way you can change the order in which you iterate.  The first loop doesn't need to be nested since you only set it when `x == y`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner loop. you dont need it. x can be used also for y in your case (with substraction)!
Also set dia to start value of 80 and divide it then.

```
int main()
{
    int the_array[5][5] =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };

    int dia = 80;

    for (int x = 4; x >= 0; --x)
    {
        the_array[x][x] = dia;
        dia /= 2;

        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
        {
            printf(" %02d ", the_array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int the_array[5][5] =
{
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
};

int dia = 5;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (x = 4; x >= 0; --x)
{
         the_array[x][x] = dia;
         dia *= 2;
 }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            printf("%d ", the_array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

You can use use one loop to change `the_array` to:

```
80 0 0 0 0 
0 40 0 0 0 
0 0 20 0 0 
0 0 0 10 0 
0 0 0 0  5
```

Then use two loop the output it:

```
0 0 0 0 80 
0 0 0 40 0 
0 0 20 0 0 
0 10 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int the_array[5][5] = {{0}};
    int x, y, dia = 80;//start from 80

    for (x = 0; x < 5; ++x){//start from 0
        for (y = 0; y < 5; ++y){
            if (x == 5 - y - 1) {
                the_array[x][y] = dia;
                dia /= 2;
            }
            printf(" %2d ", the_array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```